# LeetCode Two Sum Problem - Multidimensional Array Help Java

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I attempted the first LeetCode Problem: Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

However, I keep getting a similar runtime error:

```
 Finished in N/A
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
 at line 67, Solution.sortArr
 at line 11, Solution.twoSum
```

I am not very used to using multidimensional arrays and saw this as the perfect opportunity to use them and learn. I've provided my code, could anyone help me figure out why this is failing?

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
{
    int[] targetIndex = {0,0};

    int arrEndIndex = nums.length - 1;

    int[][] copyArr = new int[nums.length][];
    copyArr = copyArrWithIndex(nums);

    int[][] sortedArr = new int[nums.length][];
    sortedArr = sortArr(copyArr);

    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = arrEndIndex;

    int firstElement = 0;
    int secondElement = 0;

    while(firstIndex != secondIndex)
    {

        firstElement = sortedArr[firstIndex][0];
        secondElement = sortedArr[secondIndex][0];

        if(firstElement + secondElement == target)
        {
            targetIndex[0] = sortedArr[firstIndex][1];
            targetIndex[1] = sortedArr[secondIndex][1];
            break;
        }
        else if(firstElement + secondElement < target)
        {
            firstIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            secondIndex--;
        }     
    }

    return targetIndex;
}

/*
This function sorts a 2D array of ints from least to greatest based 
on the values in the first column and returns a 2D array of ints
*/

private int[][] sortArr(int[][] arr)
{

    int temp = 0;

    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = 1; 
    int firstElement = 0;
    int secondElement = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < arr[0].length)
    {

        firstElement = arr[firstIndex][0];
        secondElement = arr[secondIndex][0];

        if(firstElement < secondElement)
        {
            firstIndex++;
            secondIndex++; 
        }

        else /*if(firstElement > secondElement)*/
        {
            temp = firstElement;
            arr[firstIndex][0] = secondElement;
            arr[secondIndex][0] = temp;

            temp = firstIndex;
            arr[firstIndex][1] = secondIndex;
            arr[secondIndex][1] = temp;

            if(firstIndex != 0)
            {
                firstIndex--;
                secondIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                firstIndex++;
                secondIndex++;
            }
         }
    }

    return(arr);
  }

 /*
This function accepts a 1D array and returns a 2D array of ints with the index int in the     first 
column and the original index of the presorted number adjacently in the second
column
*/

private int [][] copyArrWithIndex(int[] arr)
{
    int[][] copyArr = new int [arr.length][2]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        copyArr[i][0] = arr[i];
        copyArr[i][1] = i;
    }

    return(copyArr);
   }
   }
```

Comment: you never do anything with `i` after you set it to 0 in `sortArr`. you probably meant to use `firstIndex` or `secondIndex`

Comment: @Chronicle thank you! I did mean to use `firstIndex` that was the main problem; I've tried a few test cases after correcting that and now it works except for the test case where there are only two elements in the test input. I'm going out of bounds in that case; I'm trying to figure out why but it's definitely a logic error on my end.